# ASUS G74 LED next to capslock LED

Tags: laptop

I am having no problems with my new G74. however, in the top left corner of my keyboard, there are 2 LEDs. There is a clear caps lock marking next to the caps lock LED. Additionally there is NO scroll lock or num lock key on the computer.

The problem is that there is no marking on the other LED. the LED turns on a little while after i start my computer and doesn't seem to turn off until i reboot usually.

I have checked all manuals given with the computer and i have searched in as many locations as i can think of.

so does anyone know what this LED indicates?

if you are wondering why i am asking this, having a light on my computer that i have no idea what it is indicating bothers me.

Comment: What is the exact model number (look on the bottom), and which country did you purchase it in?

Comment: it is "G74SX-BBK7/I7-2630QM" and it was purchased in America.

Comment: I had reboot my computer twice today. first time i turned it on today it took 5 minutes to turn on, and on a reboot it was on instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably Num Lock.

Depending on your exact G74 model, some of them come with an extended keyboard (has a keypad, including a real Num Lock button):

[image: Numlock1]

And others have an integrated num-pad in the keyboard, and Num Lock is [Fn]+[Insert] to enable/disable it:

[image: Numlock2]

From the [manual](http://support.asus.com/download/download_item_mkt.aspx?slanguage=en-us&model=G74SX) for the G74SX:

> When the numeric keypad is engaged by pressing [Fn][Ins/Num LK], **the number lock LED lights up**

Comment: thank you for the reply, although i am afraid instead of a numlock key my model only has only a calculator button, I did try pressing fn+calc, to no avail. fn insert also does not work.

Comment: so... interesting news. it is num lock. it turns out that the light toggles when i press the num lock key on my usb keyboard.